# ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update never installs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can't install MVC 3 Tools update. The installer finishes ok, but MVC 3 Tools Update never gets installed (when viewed in Control Panel's Programs and Features section). The MVC project templates remain old and can't compile projects created with a pc that actually has the MVC 3 Tools Update installed. For example, VS2010 complains about ViewBag as non-existent.

Anyone else having the same issue that MVC 3 Tools Update doesn't install?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` is built-in ASP.NET MVC 3, nothing to do with the Tools Update. If VS cannot recognize `ViewBag` you probably are not working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project or even don't have this installed.